# Problem with making a Reddit bot in python

Tags: python, praw

I'm trying to program a reddit bot, but get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
    run_bot(r, comments_replied_to)
  File "main.py", line 34, in run_bot
    comments_replied_to.append(comment.id)
AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/caz14jm7

I think I have to change append into a list, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: That's not an error message.  That's just part of a traceback.  Please show the whole traceback.

Comment: That STILL doesn't include the error message, which was, I assume, "'filter' object has no attribute 'append'".  THAT is the information we need in order to help you.

Comment: sorry, the last line of the traceback is AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'append', I forgot to add that

Comment: Right, which is exactly what I said.  My answer below will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Part of this is a version difference.  In Python 2, `filter` returned a list.  In Python 3, `filter` returns a generator, which you are treating like a list.  The filter generator does not have an append method.

So, you just need to turn it into a list:

```
            comments_replied_to = list(filter(None, comments_replied_to))
```

Or, even better (in the opinion of many):

```
            comments_replied_to = [k for k in comments_replied_to if k]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 potential solutions for you,

**solution 1:**
`Line 55` You can change like this
`comments_replied_to = List(filter(None, comments_replied_to))`

so that, your `get_saved_comments()` will return a list.
This will help you use the `append method` and `comments_replied_to.append(comment.id)` should work without any error

**Solution 2:**

`Line 60:` You can change like this
`comments_replied_to = list(get_saved_comments())`

As long as `comments_replied_to` is a list type, it will allow you to `append` method without any issues.

check this blog to have a better understanding over `append method`
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append